# Combine iTween with physics acceleration

Tags: unity-game-engine, itween

I am trying to combine [iTween](http://itween.pixelplacement.com/index.php) with physics acceleration.

[image: top view of the path]

Here is the top view of the path. The brown rectangle is made by a cube `GameObject`, with an `iTweenPath` component attached (4 nodes). The path is named `Path1`. On the left, there is a sphere (may not be seen clearly), which acts as the Actor, with `RigidBody` attached (mass = 3), was put few units above the floor.

Then, I assigned a script to the Actor, which is:

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collison) {
  iTween.MoveTo(gameObject, iTween.Hash("path", iTweenPath.GetPath("Path1"), "time", 5));
}
```

when the ball hits the ground due to gravity, it triggers the `iTween.MoveTo()`. The above works as expected.

However, I want to combine with my physics acceleration script, which is:

```
void FixedUpdate() {
  rigidbody.AddForce(transform.forward * 5.0f, ForceMode.Acceleration);
}
```

However, iTween governs the movement, made the `AddForce()` in `FixedUpdate()` no effect at all. How can I combine these two?

Comment: So you need the sphere to follow the iTween path with applied force and no iTween movements, right?

Comment: Yes. the sphere should follow the path, but its speed should be set according to the force applied to it.

Comment: ok let me try this and let you know..

Comment: do you want to use iTween path only? Or with only empty gameobject will also do?

Comment: Any solution is welcome. My goal is to allow my character to run in curve and its speed is according to physics acceleration (there are crouching & jumping actions too). Just like Temple Run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not used iTween in this solution. Just used number of empty gameobjects in array to generate path. More gameobjects in path smoother the path.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class RollBall : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public float speed=10;
    public Transform target;
    public Transform[] pathPoints;
    public int c;


void Start () 
    {
        c=0;
    }
    
    void Update () 
    {
        target.position=new Vector3(transform.position.x,transform.position.y+1f,transform.transform.position.z);
        if(target.position.z>=pathPoints[c].position.z)
        {
            if(c<pathPoints.Length)
                c++;
        }
        target.LookAt(pathPoints[c]);

        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))
        {
            rigidbody.AddForce(target.forward*speed);
        }
    }

}
```

In this target is the empty gameobject which moves with the sphere to give direction to the sphere. pathPoints is the array of empty gameobjects generating a curved path (sequence does matters). Try this code with attaching it to a sphere. Let me know [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37624/unity3d-developers) if any doubts.

Comment: I got your point. By using `target.LookAt()` and applying forward force, the character will move towards a hidden path made by a series of empty game objects. Nice solution!